# ArrayOutOfBoundException when exporting jasperreport using JRTextExporter

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using jasper reports library to add some jasper reports to my java web application, the report itself is fine, but the problem comes when I try to export it from my application using the bellow code

```
    JasperPrint jasperPrint;
try {
    //get the database connection
    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(report_path);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
    jasperReport = (JasperReport) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    //get report result
    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, connection);
    connection.close();
    if (jasperPrint.getPages().size() > 0) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        JRExporter exporter;
        exporter = new JRTextExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.CHARACTER_HEIGHT,19f);
        exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.CHARACTER_WIDTH,7f);
        exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.BETWEEN_PAGES_TEXT,"");
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);
        exporter.exportReport();
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The following error occurs when I try to export the report

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporter.exportText(JRTextExporter.java:614)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporter.exportElements(JRTextExporter.java:392)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporter.exportPage(JRTextExporter.java:369)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporter.exportReportToWriter(JRTextExporter.java:345)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporter.exportReport(JRTextExporter.java:194)
```

The line causing the error is this one 
`exporter.exportReport();`

The weird thing about this is that when I choose any other format the code runs fine and I get the report, also for `text` format if the data is less than 5 lines the report exports successfully. I searched this and found it was a bug in the jasperreports library and should be fixed in version `2.2.1` I think, I'm using jasperreports library version `5.5.1` I also used version `2.2.1` and `6.x` but the problem is still there.
It seems like it have something to do with the page width and height, but I could not know how to solve it. This is the first line of my report

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="1875" pageHeight="40" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="1875" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="b8c06aba-6b16-4020-8a9e-574d630cdbae">
```

Also I observed that when I set `isIgnorePagination="false"` the problem goes but I have empty lines at the end of the report, which I don't want.
please help, let me know the cause of the error and the fix of it if there is.

Comment: try...  jasperPrint.getPages().size()-1 in your if()

Comment: This is probably a bug in jasper reports, note when using the JRTextExporter it normally assumed that you also use pagination ignored (since you are merly generating a text output of report). We can not reproduce the error since we would need same datasource etc. either you manage to generate a [mcve] and edit your question, but probably it would be best to submit this directly to jasper report as a [bug-tracker](http://community.jaspersoft.com/bug-tracker)

Comment: I also found a relevant link http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/522668/export-text-givesarrayindexoutofboundsexception

Answer (score 1):

Some how I resolved same kind issue with my Japser Text Exporter, the issue was like below,

I am using Sub reports and the tag inside it is as below with **x** and **y** negative value because while aligning it in design mode it has to be placed out of the boundary to get proper aligned report with main,

`<reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="-6" y="-1" width="54" height="13"`

and after that there is a recordCounter in sub report and when it crosses 99 and 100 is three characters, that time I get this exception from **exportText** method **JRTextExporter** class, then I increased the width recordCounter to fit in 5 characters and now it exporting fine.

It might not be the same in your case, but just thought of sharing my isue n fix.

I am using jasperreports-6.2.0

Answer (score 0):

In my case it occurred this problem in version 4.5.1 of JasperReport.

I was using subreports to generate TXT file.

To fix it was necessary to use the same bandwidth and the width of the textField in all sub reports. In my example was the width of the band 15 and the width of the textField 14.